# How to create ECDSA keypair using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, openssl

Currently using a rather unmaintained package [sshpk](https://github.com/joyent/node-sshpk) to generate ECDSA pair (like demonstrated below) and wondering if support to generate such pair has been added natively to Node.js since?

```
import sshpk from 'sshpk';
const keyPair = sshpk.generatePrivateKey('ecdsa');
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypairsync_type_options (also in async form). Although you must specify the curve (no default) and it seems to take only the oldest name -- `prime256v1` not `nistp256`.

Comment: Is "ec" the same as "ecdsa"?

Comment: Effectively yes. X9.62 and X9.63 use the same key formats for ECDSA and ECDH/ECMQV/ECIES, so things that implement both -- like OpenSSL in nodejs -- often use a shared structure called EC. OpenSSH uses such keys only for ECDSA and labels them accordingly -- although if you look at an id_ecdsa file created by ssh-keygen below 7.8 it uses OpenSSL's 'EC PRIVATE KEY' format. (Whether to use the same key _instance_ for more than one algorithm is a security question offtopic here and belonging on security.SX or crypto.SX, but is _usually_ considered a bad idea.)